# How to solve Docker for Windows permission error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permission-denied, intersystems-iris

I am currently facing some "permission denied"-issues with Docker for Windows 10.

I am using this image: [Intersystems IRIS](https://hub.docker.com/_/intersystems-iris-data-platform)

My Dockerfile for this image is:

```
FROM store/intersystems/iris-community:2020.2.0.204.0
```

Furthermore I am using *docker-compose*, *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: '2'
services:
backend:
    container_name: iris
    build: 
        context: ./container/IRISDataPlatform
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.yaml
    volumes:
        - ./container/IRISDataPlatform/ext:/external
    ports:
        - "9091:51773"
        - "9092:52773"
    environment:
        - ISC_DATA_DIRECTORY=/external/irissys
        - ICM_SENTINEL_DIR=/external
    command: --password-file /external/password.txt
```

The problem is whenever I execute *docker-compose up -d* the container exits after some seconds and shows following message:

> [INFO] Initializing IRIS, please wait...
>
> Starting IRIS
>
> Invalid ownership for ./irisrecov
>
> Initializing IRIS, please wait...
>
> Starting IRIS
>
> Recovery failure. Startup aborted.
>
> [ERROR] Command "iris start IRIS quietly" exited with status 256
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:02:326 (374) 0 [Utility.Event]
> ISC_DATA_DIRECTORY=/external/irissys
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:02:353 (374) 0 [Utility.Event] Executing iris qlist
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:02:580 (374) 0 [Utility.Event] Versions are the same
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:02:596 (374) 0 [Utility.Event] Source /usr/irissys:
> 2020.2.0.204.0com
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:02:612 (374) 0 [Utility.Event] Destination
> /external/irissys: 2020.2.0.204.0com
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:02:627 (374) 0 [Utility.Event] Executing iris update
> IRIS directory=/usr/irissys datadir=/external/irissys
> versionid=2020.2.0.204.0com
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:02:680 (374) 0 [Utility.Event] Executing find
> /usr/irissys/ -type d -exec chmod ugo-w {} +
>
> 07/07/20-15:46:03:349 (374) 0 [Utility.Event] Executing chmod ugo-w
> /usr/irissys/
>
> [ERROR] Possible causes:
>
> [ERROR] - Incorrect user/group ownership of IRIS binaries
>
> [ERROR] - Insufficient write permissions to ISC_DATA_DIRECTORY
>
> [FATAL] Error starting InterSystems IRIS

What I tried so far:

- Adding "user"-attribute to the backend-service and set it to "root" or "irisowner" -> Both not working
- Adding "RUN adduser irisusr root && adduser irisusr irisusr" to my Dockerfile (as mentioned here: "https://community.intersystems.com/post/using-intersystems-iris-containers-docker-windows") but it ends in: *"adduser Only root may add a user or group to the system"* while *docker-compose build*

Do you know any fixes to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sequence in your Dockerfile should look like similar to this:

```
FROM intersystemsdc/iris-community:latest   
USER root   
RUN adduser irisusr root && adduser irisusr irisusr  

USER irisowner
```

You may use any template from [OpenExchang](https://openexchange.intersystems.com/)e as an example